# How to send a data in the form of a file in a channel using Eris Discord

Tags: discord, eris

I have some data in Array. I want it to send the data in a channel in the form of a `.json` file. How to do that in [Eris](https://github.com/abalabahaha/eris)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the docs [here](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs/Client#function-createMessage). So how you would send it in a channel via a file would be

```
<Client>.createMessage(<Message>.channel.id, 'Text', {file: {file.name: '<name>.json', file.file: 'Put your array data here'}})
```

I hope this helped!

Edit: The past one was wrong. The correct format is

```
<Client>.createMessage(<Message>.channel.id, 'Text', {file: {file.name: '<name>.json', file.file: 'Put your array data here'}})
```